# How to delete object in realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I check many other answers but still having problem with deleting data form database of realm.
This is my error code :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Rebel.RebelTableViewController delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fca7b40b5c0

This code is from my table view to delete:

```
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
    rowHere = indexPath.row
    // it crashes the app when I want to delete from database

    //  delete(self.todos[self.rowHere!])

    self.Rebel.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
}
```

Comment: Nobody even knows what self.Rebel is.

Comment: There are many questions on deleting object in realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get `Object` model in `viewDidLoad()`

```
var DatabaseModel: Results<ObjectClassRealm>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    DatabaseModel = realm.objects(ObjectClassRealm.self)
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
    let objectData = DatabaseModel[indexPath.row]
    RealmService.shared.delete(objectData)
}
```

Or you can delete on button click

```
@IBAction func DeleteData(_ sender: Any) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let deleteData = realm.object(ofType: ObjectClassRealm.self, 
                                  forPrimaryKey: PRIMARYKEY)
    if deleteData == nil {
        print("No data in DB")
    } else {
        RealmService.shared.delete(deleteData!)
    }
}
```

read documents of realm, also you will find many solutions for same question.